# Momentum and position for free particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, fourier-transform

In the section of 'The free particle' in 'Introduction to quantum mechanics, second edition' by Griffiths page 65. He has the wave equation as $$\Psi(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(k)e^{i(kx-\omega t)}dk$$  He then makes statements about if $\phi(k)$ has a large spread then the momentum is ill-defined. Why? Does $\phi(k)$ have such a strong influence on momentum? And how does a small spread in $\phi(k)$ correspond to a more well defined position?

Comment: This question has been discussed in [chat] (and largely solved, AFAIK). Perhaps you could post an answer yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually define $p=\hbar k$. In this post, I'll take $\hbar =1$ (see [natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units)) to simplify the notation. This means that $k=p$. This is not necessary, but IMHO this makes the arguments more transparent (besides the fact that natural units are indeed more natural once you get used to them). I usually recommend every learning physicist to try to use natural units whenever they can. If you don't like to, you can exchange $k\leftrightarrow p/\hbar$ in my answer.

In general, [the expectation value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_value_(quantum_mechanics)) of the momentum is given by
$$
\langle k\rangle= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathrm dk\ k\ |\phi(k)|^2 \tag{1}
$$
which means that $|\phi(k)|^2$ has to decrease faster than $1/k^3$ as $k\to\infty$ for $\langle k\rangle$ to be well defined. In fact, we also want $\langle k^2\rangle$ to be well defined, which means we usually want $\phi(k)$ to be $\mathcal O(k^{-2})$ as $k\to\infty$.

If $\phi(k)$ has a large spread (it doesn't decrease fast enough), then the momentum is not well-defined, because the integrals that define momentum are divergent.

> Why Does $\phi(k)$ have such a strong influence on momentum?

Well, $\phi(k)$ is the wave-function in [momentum space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_and_momentum_space#Position_and_momentum_spaces_in_quantum_mechanics), so **all** the information about the momentum of the system is contained in $\phi(k)$.

> And how does a small spread in $\phi(k)$ correspond to a more well defined position?

Note that $\phi(k)$ is the Fourier Transform of $\Psi$, so that this statement is actually equivalent to the [uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle) of the Fourier Transform.

**UPDATE**

Here we prove that both expressions $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent:
$$
\langle k\rangle=-i\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathrm dx \ \Psi^*\partial_x\Psi \tag{2}
$$

The proof is non-trivial, but in the end is just the [differentiation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Differentiation) of the Fourier Transform. To prove the equivalence, we'll make use of the [known fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Fourier_transform)
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathrm dx\ \mathrm e^{iqx}=2\pi\delta(q) \tag{3}
$$
for any $q\in\mathbb R$. Here, $\delta(q)$ is the Dirac delta function.

First, note that
$$
\Psi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int \mathrm dk\ \phi(k)\;\mathrm e^{i(kx-\omega t)} \tag{4}
$$
so that
$$
\partial_x\Psi=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int \mathrm dk\ k\;\phi(k)\;\mathrm e^{i(kx-\omega t)} \tag{5}
$$

If we make the change of variable $k\to k_1$ in $(4)$ and $k\to k_2$ in $(5)$, and plug these into $(2)$ we get
$$
\begin{align}
\langle k\rangle&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \mathrm dx \int\mathrm dk_1\int\mathrm dk_2\ \overbrace{\phi^*(k_1)\;\mathrm e^{-i(k_1x-\omega t)}}^{\Psi^*}\ \overbrace{k_2\;\phi(k_2)\;\mathrm e^{i(k_2x-\omega t)}}^{\partial_x\Psi}=\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\mathrm dk_1\int\mathrm dk_2\ k_2\ \phi^*(k_1)\;\phi(k_2)\int \mathrm dx\ \mathrm e^{i(k_2-k_1)x}
\end{align}
$$

Next, use $(3)$ to simplify the $x$ integral, where $q\equiv k_2-k_1$:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle k\rangle&=\int\mathrm dk_1\int\mathrm dk_2\ k_2\ \phi^*(k_1)\;\phi(k_2)\;\delta(k_2-k_1)=\\
&=\int\mathrm dk_1 k_1\ |\phi(k_1)|^2
\end{align}
$$
which is just $(1)$ upon the change of variables $k_1\to k$. As you can see, both expressions are equivalent, which means that you can use whichever you like the most.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could I ask a few questions. 1. Why are you using $\langle k \rangle$ as the expectation value for momentum, should it not be $\langle p \rangle$? For a free particle $k$ is the continuous variable. Are you using it since $p = \bar{h}k$? 

2. Griffiths gives the expectation value of momentum as $$\langle p \rangle = -h \int (\Psi^* \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x})dx$$ How did you get that the expectation value of momentum is proportional to the $\int k |\phi(k)|^2dk$?

Comment: @JohnDoe good questions! 1) yes, it should be $\langle p\rangle$, but as $p=\hbar k$, we usually write $k$ instead of $p$ to economise the typing (so that there are less factors of $\hbar$). 2) Both expressions are equivalent. I'll add some details for both questions into my answer. See the edits!

Comment: Thanks for the detail, it makes sense. Griffiths writes the following on page 71. We deal with the bound state $E < 0$. Assumeing the delta-function potential, we get that the time independent Schrodinger equation is: $$\frac{-\hbar}{2m}\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} - \alpha\delta(x)\psi = E \psi$$ In the region $x < 0$, $V(x)=0$ so $$\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} = -\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}\psi = \kappa^2 \psi$$ where the general solution is $$\psi(x) = Ae^{-\kappa x} + Be^{\kappa x}$$ Griffiths writes that the first term blows up as $x \to - \infty$ so we take $A= 0$.

Comment: **Questions:** 

1. Why can't $\psi(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$? Why do we avoid this case? Do we avoid this since we are seeking normalizable solutions?

2. How can $E < 0$, what physical system would have a negative total energy?

Comment: @JohnDoe I'm glad I could help :) In general, it is discouraged to answer to unrelated questions in the comments. I suggest you to ask a new question in the main page. If you do so, tell me and I'll aswer you there! (people don't like answers in the comment section, because they are difficult to find, so they won't be useful for future readers: we want questions easy to find on google, so that they shall help other people. A question answered in the comments won't ever be found, and so its useless). Please, ask this question in the main page, so we don't get in trouble :)

Comment: I understand, I will do this from now. I have a question related to proving equation (3) which you used above. I have asked this in a [new question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241311/using-plancherels-theorem-on-delta-function), let me know what you think., thanks.